# Problems with deploying the AEX9 contract using the golang SDK

Tags: sdk, smartcontracts

I am using golang SDK compile deployment token AEX9 fungible-token. Aes when an error is as follows:

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zAoTs.png)

Here are the methods I called, and the parameters I passed in

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nIWSX.png)

What should I do to fix this issue?
I will be grateful for any help!

Answer (score 1):

Try to change the deployment line to:

```
ctID, _, err := contract.Deploy(string(expected), "init", []string{"\"AAA\"", "18", "\"ABC\"", "Some(1000000000000000000)"}, config.CompilerBackendFATE)
```

it does work and the error you got doesn’t appear anymore.